# Detecting when styles disabled

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility

What's the best way to detect, with JS, if the user has disabled your stylesheets? Is there a reliable way even?

Comment: You could check the computed style for certain elements and see if they don't match what you declare in your stylesheet.

Comment: check if the if the styles you set in your file apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something easy would be to check the body background color for instance.

However, how likely is it someone disables CSS and not Javascript? (dunno what you use it for obviously)

Comment: I dunno how likely either. The site I'm working has very high accessibility demands though, and for certain elements (eg carousel) having js without css ends up with a confusing interface which doesn't seem to do anything ( as the carousel uses a lot of css styles )

Comment: Eventhough there's clear standards for accessibility, it's a bit hard to figure out which things to go for on a budget. I usually have an approach that goes with using link titles, proper structure on the site so it can be easily tabbed, good contrast, clear buttons, divide content and styling etc. Test by keyboard navigating yourself. A really well made site will be accessible on it's own if the author follows up with the content. Only 2-3% disable JS, fewer would disable CSS, and newer screen readers hopefully aren't as bad as they used to.

Answer (score 6):

How about asking them?

```
<div style="display:none">This site relies on CSS, please go to our <a href="noncss.html">CSS free version of this site</a></div>
```

Comment: Pet peeve here at SO. People voting down without commenting why.

Comment: It certainly wasn't me that downvoted. Seems like a valid solution. However 99% of the time that a user would have CSS disabled and JS enabled is for a screen reader or some other sort of accessibility tool. Perhaps using `CSS challenged version` is not the best choice or words.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a small, empty div sit on the screen. When the page loads, use JS to check the 'display' property of that div. If it's 'none', then your css has successfully been loaded. If not, they may have to turned off / changed your styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in control of the stylesheet you can have a "calibration" style.
Have a classname that applies some CSS property to an element. A good cross-browser safe property can be background-color.

When loading your JS try to dinamically create an element and apply the classname to it. Check if the properties match (the one on the element with the one you're expecting).

BoltClock's comment comes close. You can use `window.getComputedStyles(calibrationElement, null)` but that will fail in older IE browser versions.

See documentation for [getComputedStyles](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle)

Feel free to remove the "calibration" node after you've checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your primary external or inline stylesheet is loaded before the script, you can use this:

```
if (document.styleSheets.length){} // stylesheets are disabled
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.styleSheets

It's IE5+ compatible too as per: http://www.jr.pl/www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

The caveat is that, if styles are turned off after the window has loaded (which only causes a browser repaint), the document.styleSheets object won't change on the fly. Additionally, as noted in the comments below, this will not work for Firefox when using the View -> Page Style -> No Style feature, for which styles are still loaded, just not applied to the view.

To detect the initial state across browsers, or changes on [window.onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize), it can be done with a [style reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167541/1647538) on the body, with the following code placed *after* `<body>` or in a DOMContentLoaded event:

```
if (document.body.clientWidth !== document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
  // Styles are disabled or not applied
}
```

This works if you use `body { margin: 0; }` in your stylesheets (with no particular custom width), because it makes the `body` element the same width as `documentElement` (a.k.a. the `<hmtl>` element) while styles are active.

When styles are turned off or disabled, the `body.clientWidth` will revert to the browser's default body width, which always has a margin ([8px by default in CSS 2.1 major browsers](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) ) and therefore different from `documentElement.clientWidth`.

Should your site design use a specific margin other than 8px for the body, here is an alternative option:

```
if (document.body.clientWidth === document.documentElement.clientWidth-16) {
  // user styles are disabled or not applied (IE8+ default browser style applies)
}
```

Comment: I turned off styles in firefox 28.0 through View->Page Style->No Style, and tried both approaches you provided, they don't work. document.styleSheets.length is always greater than 0, and document.body.clientWidth !== document.width always returns true.

Comment: @Stack0verflow Thanks for the report. It seem that the 'No Style' Firefox option does not imply Styles are in fact disabled (in that, it's different from Webkit's 'Disable Styles' option). Styles are just taken off the view but they are always loaded. I'll look into it for a revised solution.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Safari, part of the difficulty is that with CSS off the elements still report CSS attributes. But if you test on the actual rendering of a property then you can tell. Width is probably the simplest (and most common) property you can test on.

Below is a sample script (it uses jQuery, but could easily be un-jQueryfied) that will test for CSS. We just load an empty div on the page, give it a width of 3px using CSS, and then test that div's width. If the width is not 3 then CSS is disabled. Obviously you have to make sure that this doesn't colide with any other styles you might have that could cause the width to be other than 3. But it gives the general idea.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">     
            #testCSS {width: 3px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testCSS"></div>
        <div id="message"></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                if (jQuery("#testCSS").width() != 3) jQuery("#message").html("CSS Disabled");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: sorry about the messy code example. It doesn't seem to like my code tags. Here's a JSfiddle with the code. Obviously you won't be able to disable CSS and test there, but you can pull the code from it: http://jsfiddle.net/3FvdL/1/