# Is Mapbox compatible with Section 508 regulations for accessibility on U.S. government websites?

Tags: mapping, accessibility, mapbox, section508

We are considering creating pages that feature data visualization on a Federal government website, and are interested in using Mapbox API. There are concerns about it not being Section 508 compliant  regarding accessibility. Does anyone know of any precedent where mapbox was successfully used on a government website, or how to make it accessible regarding Section 508 guidelines?

Comment: My [other answer on maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659051/google-maps-508-accessibility-without-styles/16060809#16060809) may be a good starting point for the second part

Answer (score 0):

The Mapbox web API uses a fork of the open-source Leaflet.js (http://leafletjs.com) library for rendering web maps, so Mapbox's compliance with accessibility standards depends directly on Leaflet meeting those standards.

Currently, Leaflet is **not** Section 508-compliant, but they are working on it. There is a great discussion going on right now on Leaflet's GitHub repository about this very issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3210

The biggest problems seem to be with the basemap tiles (screen readers will read the file name of every tile) and the map control buttons.

(Note that this answer is specifically about their Javascript library. I'm not sure about their iOS or Android SDKs.)